# Sort and Return Top 5 Rows with Greatest Values

Tags: r

For this dataset, I would like to order the `Var1` by the corresponding frequency in order from largest to smallest and take the top 5 largest by row. I've been using the functions `rank()`, `sort()`, and `order()` with no avail.

```
                     Var1 Freq
2                Moderate   33
3                  Luxury   31
4                 Couples   31
5  Families with Children   33
6               Nightlife   23
7                  Europe   60
8            Architecture   23
9                   Drink   58
10        Northern Europe   27
11                 Skiing   29
```

Ideally, I would like the final output to be:

`Var1 Freq
7                  Europe   60
9                   Drink   58
5  Families with Children   33
2                Moderate   33
3                  Luxury   31`

When I use the functions stated above, R returns a series of numbers such that are either jibberish or it will only return the `Freq` column in a ranked order.

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to post an R question we can help with. That includes a representative sample of data, the code that has or hasn't worked, and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution.

```
df %>% top_n(5, Freq) %>% arrange(-Freq)
```

This gives you the top 5 scores in order.

```
#                     Var1 Freq
# 1                 Europe   60
# 2                  Drink   58
# 3               Moderate   33
# 4 Families with Children   33
# 5                 Luxury   31
# 6                Couples   31
```

Note that 6 entries are included due to a tie.

---

If you just want the top 5 regardless of ties, then you can use this:

```
df %>% arrange(-Freq) %>% filter(row_number() <= 5)

#                     Var1 Freq
# 1                 Europe   60
# 2                  Drink   58
# 3               Moderate   33
# 4 Families with Children   33
# 5                 Luxury   31
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner. It uses `order` and `head`.

```
head(dat[order(dat$Freq, decreasing = TRUE), ], 5)
#                    Var1 Freq
#7                 Europe   60
#9                  Drink   58
#2               Moderate   33
#5 Families with Children   33
#3                 Luxury   31
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Architecture", "Couples", "Drink", 
"Europe", "Families with Children", "Luxury", "Moderate", "Nightlife", 
"Northern Europe", "Skiing"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(33L, 
31L, 31L, 33L, 23L, 60L, 23L, 58L, 27L, 29L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 1L,                                     3L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Architecture", "Couples", "Drink", 
                                                         "Europe", "Families with Children", "Luxury", "Moderate", "Nightlife", 
                                                         "Northern Europe", "Skiing"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(33L, 
                                                                                                                   31L, 31L, 33L, 23L, 60L, 23L, 58L, 27L, 29L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
DFDT <- as.data.table(dat)
DFDT[order(-Freq)][1:5]

                     Var1 Freq
1:                 Europe   60
2:                  Drink   58
3:               Moderate   33
4: Families with Children   33
5:                 Luxury   31
```